# jQuery $.post();

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a question about $.post() in jQuery. the general syntax is :

```
jQuery.post( url, [ data ], [ success(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ], [ dataType ] );
```

I'd be grateful if someone could shed light on what exactly data,textStatus are along with an example if possible

Thanks!

Comment: Good question... I know what `data` is (literally, the data passed back by the AJAX'd page), but no idea for textStatus.

Comment: textStatus is the status that was coming back from the server.

Comment: If I had to guess at `textStatus` I would say it's the text status returned in the HTTP response ("OK" or "Bad Request")

Comment: is data the variable that is echoe'd back ?

Comment: @Anant No, I believe it is the data that is returned to you from the server.

Comment: I don't understand. WHat exactly is returned? I mean how would we write that in PHP

Comment: @Anant you're getting back **exactly** what you output in PHP (so you'd either `print` or `echo` something out - it could be `json`, XML, or HTML). Your job is to tell jQuery what you're expecting back. If you're expecting `json`, it will parse it as `json` (and error out if it isn't valid `json`). You can also tell jQuery that you are expected XML or HTML and it will handle it as such.

Answer (score 2):

`data` is the response you get back from the server. It depends on the `dataType` that you specify. If you specify `json` as the argument to the `dataType` parameter, jQuery will interpret the data received from the server as `json`.

`textStatus` gives you information about the response, as in whether it was successful, or if something bad happened. [Possible values](http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg36499.html) are:

- `success`
- `error`
- `notmodified`
- `timeout`
- `parsererror`

If your `success` handler is called, then the value of `textStatus` is most likely `success`.

You will get a `parsererror` if the data is of an unexpected type. For example, if you specified that `dataType` is `json`, but the server returned XML, you will get a `parsererror` and your `error` handler will be called.

Comment: Is there a link that describes this?  I couldn't find anything in the JQuery docs myself.

Comment: @KLee1 oops - forgot to link to the source. I've edited my answer. I'm assuming that you're talking about `textStatus`?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/, the comments are correct

> The success callback function is passed the returned data, which will be an XML root element or a text string depending on the MIME type of the response. It is also passed the text status of the response.

Answer (score 0):

And if you are looking for a .NET version...

http://encosia.com/2009/04/07/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/

Comment: This link doesn't deal with the arguments to the success function in post, just post itself.